# How to descend several levels in find results array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-2.0

Calling Cake's find method on my table like this:

```
$this->Client->find('all',['recursive' => -1])
```

returns

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Client' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Intel Corporation',
        'website' => 'www.intel.com',
        'address' => '2200 Mission College Blvd.',
        'city' => 'Santa Clara',
        'state' => 'CA',
        'zip' => '95054'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Client' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'name' => 'Motorola Mobility LLC',
        'website' => 'www.motorola.com',
        'address' => '222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza',
        'city' => 'Chicago',
        'state' => 'IL',
        'zip' => '60654'
    )
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'Client' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'name' => 'Nokia',
        'website' => 'www.nokia.com',
        'address' => '6000 Connection Drive',
        'city' => 'Irving',
        'state' => 'TX',
        'zip' => '75039'
    )
),)
```

What I want is to remove the redundant 'Client' array level:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => 'Intel Corporation',
    'website' => 'www.intel.com',
    'address' => '2200 Mission College Blvd.',
    'city' => 'Santa Clara',
    'state' => 'CA',
    'zip' => '95054'
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'id' => '3',
    'name' => 'Motorola Mobility LLC',
    'website' => 'www.motorola.com',
    'address' => '222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza',
    'city' => 'Chicago',
    'state' => 'IL',
    'zip' => '60654'
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'id' => '4',
    'name' => 'Nokia',
    'website' => 'www.nokia.com',
    'address' => '6000 Connection Drive',
    'city' => 'Irving',
    'state' => 'TX',
    'zip' => '75039'
),
```

);

I'd like to do this in native Cake, with a param call or something, but if I have to do it in a php array function, please explain.  It's basically data for paginating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just how Cake does it.

Are you sure moving the inner array is even necessary? You can just use it as is...

Anyway, moving the inner array is rather trivial:

```
foreach ($clients as & $client) {
    $client = $client['Client'];
}
```